# If I paste the following code into CKeditor5 (source mode). The data disappears on reload of data

Tags: ckeditor5

If I copy the following into the Source window of CKeditor5 it looks ok when switching back to WYSIWYG. I then submit the data to a database. The data get's saved to the database correctly. When loading it back into the CKeditor5 window from the database, nothing appears. It only seems to do this when there are Word tags involved. What can I do?

```
<p class=MsoNormal>Also lists are here:<o:p></o:p></p>

<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst style='text-indent:-18.0pt;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><![if !supportLists]>
    <span
style='mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin'>
        <span
style='mso-list:Ignore'>1.
            <span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>
        </span>
    </span><![endif]>Item 1
    <o:p></o:p>
</p>
```

What can I do to prevent this problem? When I reload the page and it pulls the same data into the CKeditor nothing appears. Click "source" and still nothing appears.